# Background color not changed for the tr or h4 tag in excel formatting in PHP

Tags: php, html, excel

Here is the block of code:

```
if(!empty($result0))
{
    if($rows_header = mysqli_fetch_array($result0))
    {

        $course_header=$rows_header["course_id"];
        $header='
        <center>
            <tr style="background-color:#002C5F;height:250px;">
                <th>
                    <h4 style="font-size:20px;background-color:#002C5F;" >Course Name: '.$rows_header["course name"].'</h4>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </center>
        <table>
            <tr style="background-color:#002C5F;color:white;">
                <th style="font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; font-weight:300;"><p>Course Code: '.$rows_header["course_id"].'</p></th>
                <th style="font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; font-weight:300;"><p>Room: '.$rows_header["room"].'</h4></th>
                <th style="font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; font-weight:300;"><p>Schedule: '.$rows_header["starting"].'-'.$rows_header["ending"].'</p></th>
                <th style="font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; font-weight:300;"><p>Days:'.$rows_header["day"].'</p></th>
                <th style="font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; font-weight:300;"><p>Term: '.$rows_header["term"].'</p></th>
                <th style="font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; font-weight:300;"><p>Year: '.$rows_header["year"].'</p></th>
            </tr>
            <tr></tr>
        </table>';
        echo $header;
    }
}
```

Screenshot output:
http://prntscr.com/j2iret

> in the screenshot, the row for the course code etc.. has background color, i am able to put background colors for the entire row for it.. however if i put background-color for the  tag or  tag of course name, it's not changing its background-color to blue.. my problem is i want to make the entire row of a2-f2 and a1 up to f1. however it;s not changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, your `HTML` code looks pretty messed up: you tried to declare a table row outside the scope of a `table` tag and there was a misplaced `h4` tag closure replacing a `p` tag closure (`p` tags inside table elements are basically unnecessary, unless if stylized with `CSS`).

The following `HTML` code should produce what you are looking for:

```
<table style="background-color: #002c5f; color: white; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; font-size: 20px; font-weight: 300;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th style="height: 80px;" colspan="6" align="center">Course Name: '.$rows_header["course name"].'</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Course Code: '.$rows_header["course_id"].'</th>
            <th>Room: '.$rows_header["room"].'</th>
            <th>Schedule: '.$rows_header["starting"].'-'.$rows_header["ending"].'</th>
            <th>Days:'.$rows_header["day"].'</th>
            <th>Term: '.$rows_header["term"].'</th>
            <th>Year: '.$rows_header["year"].'</th>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```